# Can i parse JSON on the main thread if I have the file locally

Tags: android

I need to know whether I will be able to read (parse) a big (1500-2500 lines) JSON  if i have it in the device for offline usage and do it on the main thread? I think it shouldnt be a problem but its only a suggestion.

Comment: yes, you can. that's not very big a file.

Comment: So if i separate it into smaller files will it be alright?

Comment: you should try it, see that it is parsed in a blink, and get on with it.

Comment: I respectfully disagree. This kind of thing involving disk I/O and parsing adds up to tens or hundreds of milliseconds quickly and is often the difference between the app feeling sluggish and snappy. This makes a big impact to the user experience of the app.

Comment: I really appreciate the input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, but I wouldn't recommend it. It'll result in a pause that isn't ideal. It's not hard to offload that to an `AsyncTask` or some other means of moving it away from the main thread.

Comment: It isnt hard but it requires implementing a listener interface and callbacks. i was thinking of a way to save some typing and objects creation

Comment: It doesn't (necessarily) require implementing a listener interface/callbacks. Often you can do any necessary work in the `onPostExecute` method. Don't opt for saving on a little typing and object creation over a better experience for your user. You've probably already done almost as much typing on this question as you would need to do for implementing an `AsyncTask`.

Comment: Doing that means nesting the json reader async tasks in every normal class. so i have 100 classes with 100 async task classes nested within them doing the same thing

Comment: Unless there is another way that i dont know of

Comment: If you have a 100 classes doing the same thing, that says to me you need to rethink your class design. Perhaps you need a common base class. Hard to say exactly without seeing your code though.

Comment: Lets say each of the hundred activities needs diferefnt info for its views from the big json file. in order from me to get it straight from on post execute this means that i have to place the same async json  reader within each activity? I meant 100 similar nested async tasks fetching json not 100 similar activities

Comment: You have 100 different activities with different view hierarchies? In that case, perhaps that might require 100 similar nested `AsyncTask`s. Even so, you could have one main `AsyncTask` and anonymous classes extending it with different `onPostExecute` methods in each `Activity`. You could also consider separating out a data access layer to read the JSON once and just work with the data model after that. Given that your design currently seems to involve 100 different activities and loads the JSON for every activity, I would even more so encourage doing this work asynchronously to avoid delays.

Comment: Thanks to you i came to a sensible decision. i will have one asynctask class that will read the json for any given key and one interface OnTextReceivedListener and every activity will use those two :-) thanks

Comment: Oh but what if i need a set of 3-4 different strings?

Comment: Actually i can pass a linked hash set of keys and get a linked hash set of corresponding values in return (or hashmap)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but if you are performing a big task it could freeze your UI (it depends on which lifecycle state you are parsing) but as user kabuko suggest you should start another thread in an `AsyncTask` or `AsyncTaskLoader`.